# What's the difference between "you are not really lucky." and " you are really not lucky."?

Tags: grammar, difference

I just want to know
 "you are not really lucky."   and 
"you are really not lucky."
  them which one is correct in both of them. And if  both are correct then is  there any difference between them ?

Comment: not really = not very, really not = utterly not.